# how i can set a listener on a carrousel with data from value/array.xml?

Tags: android, image, drag-and-drop

i have 12 image in my file array.xml, i want to set a listener wwhen I click on the image in the carousel. I want to know what image I selected ?

my array.xml

```
resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<array name="entries">
    <item>@drawable/pic1</item>     
    <item>@drawable/pic2</item>         
    .       
    .                   
</array>
```

Comment: Your "carousel" should have setOnItemClickListener or setOnItemSelectedListener methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can set position of your image.
How you display images .
in gridview or in LIstView.?

you can use this.

```
setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(HelloViewActivty.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

A fantastic tutorial for this is on  [Image Display](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-gallery-example/)

Comment: public void onItemClick(CarouselAdapter<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {    
  //int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier("belier", "drawable", "com.carouseldemo.main"); 
    
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position=" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: but I want to make a listener on the selected image in value/array.xml